# UITextView text arrangement

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

How can `UITextView` text be done from top to bottom from left to right? like this! Thank you for your reply.

**Screenshot:**
[image]

Thank you!It works!I try
textView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi / 2)
textView.transform = textView.transform.scaledBy(x: 1, y: -1)
But content size not changed!The position of the newline is not accurate.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ectTK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try it.

```
yourTextView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi/2)
```

You can easily change the rotation map with using some changes on `rotationAngle` depends on `angle`